# error of transforming pyspark dataframe to numpy array in order to run lightgbm

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark, databricks, lightgbm

I would like to run lighGBM.LGBMRegressor on databricks cluster by pyspark.

My code was developed based on :

https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html#lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.fit

```
 import lightgbm as lgb

 gbm_regressor = lgb.LGBMRegressor(...)

 gbm_regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Here, x_train and y_train are pyspark dataframe and list. 
Based on the above link, the fit() API must be:

```
  X (array-like or sparse matrix of shape = [n_samples, n_features]) – Input feature matrix.
  y (array-like of shape = [n_samples]) – The target values (class labels in classification, real numbers in regression).
```

I have to transform X and y to array by numpy.

```
  new_x_train = np.array(x_train.select(x_train.columns).collect())
```

but, it took long time to do the collection even though I have allocated enough memory for it.
Finally, I got error:

```
 Error while obtaining a new communication channel
 ConnectException error: This is often caused by an OOM error that causes the connection to the Python REPL to be closed. Check your query's memory usage.
```

My data for x_train can be 40 GB (with 30 million rows) and the driver node has 128 GB memory.

Could anybody help me find why I got this error?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems [like the driver crashed](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/21454/connectexception-error.html) because of an Out of memory exception and after that, it's not able to establish a new connection with the driver. Please try below options

- Increase driver-side memory and then retry.
- You can look at the spark job which give you more info on data flow.

Spark operations are materialized lazily and thus all processing will happen only after action is called. If you see OOM error sometimes then I recommend to check heap util and GC patterns on driver.

Additionally check the configuration for `**spark.driver.maxResultSize**`

Additional reference:

https://forums.databricks.com/topics/spark+out+of+memory.html

Hope it helps.